# How can i use rgb color from Disital color meter in Flutter application?

Tags: dart, flutter

is it possible to use RGB colour in Flutter. for Example in iOS we use UIColor(red:1/255.0, green: 102/255.0,blue: 112/255.0,alpha: 1).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381968/flutter-dart-convert-hex-color-string-to-color/50382196#50382196 or use     new Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Flutter provides some ways to construct the color.

From [the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html):

```dart
Color c = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);
Color c = const Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0x42, 0xA5, 0xF5);
Color c = const Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 165, 245);
Color c = const Color.fromRGBO(66, 165, 245, 1.0);
```