# I want to use a hexadecimal code from firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, hex, background-color, hashcode

I am new to Firebase and I finally got the data from Firebase to flutter.
I work with colors and each card has a color and color nummer.

I have in Firebase:
A field colorCode, which is a String and has a value '0xFFFFB142'

In Flutter I tried to do it like this:

```
final int colorCode = list[index]['colorCode'].hashCode;

                            Container(
                              height: 25.0,
                              width: 25.0,
                              color: Color(colorCode),
                            ),
```

I get no failure, but I see no color.

It has to be an int, but it is a hexadecimal in a string code.
When I try in Firebase a int, I got a failure because it is hex.

Update:
Thank you all for your help so far! 
I have input the code myself in Firebase. It is the same you normally put in that place, like color: Color(0xFFFFB142), where FFB142, is the color #FFB142
In Firebase I have used a String, because an int or plain code isn't allowed.
With my code, when I print it: it got 171924876, that's not the right color code.

I have tried this:

```
                    final dynamic colorCode =
                        list[index]['colorCode'].toString();

                    print(colorCode); // the right color code is printend: 0xFFFFB142
```

And when I put this in:

```
                            Container(
                              height: 25.0,
                              width: 25.0,
                              color: Color(0xFFFFB142),
```

It works fine, but I have for each item another colorCode in Firebase.

I find it very strange that I got this error message, because I don't want an int there, but a colorcode like 0xFFFFB142

```
 type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: What is the result of printing the `colorCode` variable unto the console?

Comment: The Color constructor as mentioned in ([Color Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)) takes in an int value:
 

**Color(int value)** so you **can't use a String** instead. this **will not work Color("your_color")**.

Comment: If the end result is you need and int, then before storing in firebase, convert the Hex to and Int and store it as an int.

Comment: Thanks so far. I have edit my question. It is strange that er is an int value, because the code I use normally isn't an int but a hex.

Comment: Hex is just one way of representing an int, as is decimal (which is what you printed). However the number `171924876` isn't a very good color. Where did you get it and how did you get it into Firebase?

Comment: The number 171924876 is what I get when I print the colorCode after the code: list[index]['colorCode'].hashCode; it seems to convert the original code: 0xFFFFB142. So I removed the .hashCode and then I get the code 0xFFFFB142 printed. That is the good colorCode and when I put the colorCode as 0xFFFFB142 in Color(0xFFFFB142) then is works fine. But when I put Color(colorCode) then I get the failure.

Comment: So, add the code from the answer and then where you would have used `Color(colorCode)` use `convertToColor(colorCode)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function that truncates the `0x` and parses the rest as hex.

```
Color convertToColor(String prefixedHex) => Color(int.parse(
      prefixedHex.substring(2),
      radix: 16,
    ));
```

Comment: It create a new string starting at the third character, i.e. `FFFFB142`

Comment: Thank you for your help. The complete code is something I fill in myself. So is I have to fill in the code without the first two characters?

Comment: I have edit my question, hope I am more clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution to convert the string code '#FFB142' to a color code by using a package: Flutter_Color.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_color

Code I used:

```
import 'package:flutter_color/flutter_color.dart';

final String colorCode = list[index]['colorCode'];

                            Container(
                              height: 25.0,
                              width: 25.0,
                              color: HexColor(colorCode),
```

So I imported the package, let the color code be a string and used HexColor instead of Color.

Hope this simple solution will help others also.
Thank all the others here for pointing me out in the right direction. In the end it was not about firebase, but converting a string to a color code and so I googled this package.

Comment: Or you could do it in a few lines like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381968/flutter-dart-convert-hex-color-string-to-color/50382196#50382196 It wasn't clear from your question that you had a #RRGGBB code

Comment: Thanks Richard, for all your help! To be honest, the solution with this package is for a beginner like me easier.