# Why does this color list not work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to colour Containers in a ListView Builder using a list of colours. This is the list and it is of type List< Color >

```
final colours = charts.MaterialPalette.purple.makeShades(listOfTypes.length);
```

This is the ListView builder

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount: listOfTypes.length,
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext cxt, int index){
  return Container(
   child: Text(listOfTypes[index]),
   color: colours[index],
  );
  })
```

I think that 'color : colours[index]' is not of the correct type but I'm not sure how to convert it to the type it needs. I use the list of colours somewhere else as well where it currently works so I'm not able to simply remake the list as the type error will just move. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: let us know what type of List is colours!, its definitely not List<Color> or wrong Color class

Comment: It's `List<charts.Color>` as I've mentioned on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This method `charts.MaterialPalette.purple.makeShades(listOfTypes.length)` returns List<charts.Color>. With that, you need to convert `charts.Color` to `Color`. Either convert it from [rgbaHexString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382196/2497859) or from RGBA. Choose either from the two.

```dart
// Call hexStringToColor(hexStringToColor(colours[index].rgbaHexString));
hexStringToColor(String code) {
  return Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}

// Call rgbaToColor(colours[index].r, colours[index].g, colours[index].b, colours[index].a)
rgbaToColor(int r, int g, int b, int a) {
  return Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);
}
```