# is there any alternative for Hex code error in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
i have imported "Hexcolor" package and i got an error Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart'.

and this is the output :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgeDt.png)

can someone help me

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381968/flutter-dart-convert-hex-color-string-to-color/50382196#50382196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this much code and get rid of the hex color package.

Add this code to utils or a similar directory.

```dart
class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll('#', '');
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Usage

```dart
Container(
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   color: HexColor('#00FF00')
)
```